# Creating Google calendar reminder every month on the 15 but not at Saturdays or Fridays

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

I would like to create a reminder on Google Calendar every month on the 15th, but if the 15th in that month is a Friday/Saturday, I want it automatically to set it to the closest Sunday/Thursday. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible in Google Calendar.

A possible workaround might be to create the reminder for the 14th, which would catch all Friday-situations (if I understand correctly, you would want a notification on Thursday if the 15th is a Friday, and one on Sunday if the 15th falls on a Saturday). This would always give you a notification on-time, even if too early in most months.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. About your idea - what if the 14 is Friday/Saturday?

Comment: Then the notification will be seen on Sunday, which is the intended behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why would it be seen only on Sunday...

Comment: I was assuming that the user is not present on Fridays and Saturdays. If they are, of course they will see it earlier. In any case they will have been notified on time.