# How do I set a recurring event that takes place on the 15th each month but is NOT a weekend?

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders, icalendar

I'm trying to enter in a reminder for payday.  I'm paid on the 15th of each month.  However, if the 15th falls on a Saturday or Sunday, I'm paid on Friday.  I have no problem entering a recurring event on the 15th.  It's not having it fall on a weekend that I can't figure out.

Someone asked a [similar question here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127816/creating-google-calendar-reminder-every-month-on-the-15-but-not-at-saturdays-or) but that is always setting a reminder on the 14, so that some months it would be early. It seems this person was trying to make Friday events fall on a Thursday and Sunday events fall on a Monday.  I want anything on Saturday or Sunday to fall on Friday.

I'm hoping to make an .ics event that I would import into my calendar.  [This solution](https://woorkup.com/google-calendar-last-day-of-month/#comment-51630) worked for me to enter the event for the last day of the month but I can't figure out how to edit it to work on the 15th.  I was trying to edit BYSETPOS and it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Beth, happy to reopen this for you with your current changes.  The main reason it was marked as a duplicate was that the answer is likely the same as the other question, that it's not possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .ics with the following code to set up a recurring event that occurs on the 15th of the month except when the 15th falls on a weekend. If both the 14th and the 15th fall on a weekend, the event will occur on the 13th.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
VERSION:2.0  
BEGIN:VEVENT   
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=13,14,15;BYSETPOS=-1  
SUMMARY:PAYDAY  
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20220615  
SEQUENCE:0  
DESCRIPTION:   
END:VEVENT  
END:VCALENDAR
```